# How to use listFilesAndDirs to get only directories without operating recursively

Tags: java, apache-commons, fileutils

I'd like, for the simplicity of the code, to use `FileUtils.listFilesAndDirs`.
I want to get all the directories in the given path, without looking at sub-directories (running recursively)

I tried this:

```
Collection<File> dirs = FileUtils.listFilesAndDirs(pathFile, DirectoryFileFilter.DIRECTORY, null);
```

but it only returned the *containing* directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that this is not possible with `FileUtils.listFilesAndDirs`. If you dont need to use `FileUtils.listFilesAndDirs` you can do the following:

```
pathFile.listFiles((java.io.FileFilter) FileFilterUtils.directoryFileFilter())
```

Comment: No problem. I deleted the additional info cause it works as designed. I tested the method and thought the result listed also the sub-dirs...but it doesnt. I found no way to get this method working without recursion.